# Log files on In-Memory Optimized Table enabled databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a problem with log files on In Memory-Optimized Tables (IMOT) enabled databases. The log file are too big and not allows to shrink it. Anyone can recommend what to do to take control over the log file size?